# Testing relation between two integers in a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

This is what I read:

> One can test if there exist integers x and y such that
>
> $c\times x + j = d \times y + k$,
>
> if $(k-j)mod(gcd(c,d)) = 0$

How can one see that?

--

PS: I understand what $gcd$ and $mod$ operations do.

--

PSS: Source: 
1st frame of slide 6 within
http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~collberg/Teaching/553/2011/Handouts/Handout-33.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we let $c=td$, we have that:

$$tx-y=\frac{k-j}{d}$$

Noting that $gcd(td,d)=d$, the implication is obvious.

Comment: but what if c = 3, and d =2? can one still assume 'c = td'?

Comment: Then their gcd is $1$, and anything $=0 \pmod 1$